# How to get one random float number from two ranges (python)

Tags: python, random, colors, floating-point, range

I need to choose a random float number in two ranges in python:

```
0. < n < 0.2  or  0.8 < n < 1.
```

Right now I only have one range:

```
random.uniform(0, 0.2)
```

The full line (I'm mapping warm color hsv values):

```
couleur = hsv2rgb(random.uniform(0, 0.2), 1, 1))
```

If someone could help... !

Comment: by taking a single range such as `[0; 0.4]` and mapping it to required ones?

Comment: It needs to be from on or the other

Answer (score 4):

You can do a weighted selection between the intervals:

```
from numpy import random

def uniform_two(a1, a2, b1, b2):
    # Calc weight for each range
    delta_a = a2 - a1
    delta_b = b2 - b1
    if random.rand() < delta_a / (delta_a + delta_b):
        return random.uniform(a1, a2)
    else:
        return random.uniform(b1, b2)

print uniform_two(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a random number in `0 < n < 0.4` and map the upper half of that interval to your desired range.

```
nbr = random.uniform(0, 0.4)
if nbr >= 0.2:
    nbr += 0.6
```